# How do I find a Facebook "friend request" that I declined?

Tags: facebook

How do I find an old "friend request" that I declined?

Comment: Did you try looking up your friend by his/her name and submit the friend request from your end?

Answer (score 8):

In order to find Facebook friend-requests that you previously received, but chose to postpone at the time using the **Not Now** option, you should:

1. Click on the *Friend Requests* icon on the top menu-bar. A menu will open.
2. Click on **See All** at the bottom of that menu.

There, you will see all of your previously-received friend-requests. For each one, you can click on **Confirm** or **Delete Request**, if you wish.

Facebook does not offer a way for you to see friend-requests that you previously rejected explicitly or deleted.

Answer (score 2):

If you have "following" activated, and if the person who you declined didn't unfollow you (manually), you should find that person in your followers, from where you can send a friend request.

Comment: This is a clever way to solve the issue, I found some of rejected requests there. Thank you!